# Custom Fields box in the post editor: Replace textareas with input elements

Tags: custom-field, admin, post-editor

I am developing a theme for a specicific use case which uses custom fields. To emphasize that the values are always single line, I would like to replace the textareas with input fields.

What is a good way to go about this?